# Как сделать открытие следующего блока из квадрата, расположенного в первом блоке?

Tags: javascript

Разместил [вот здесь](http://prokrutka.sozdanie-sajtov73.ru/#) всю реализацию. В каком направлении думать, чтобы реализовать раскрытие нового блока как-бы из квадрата, который расположен в 1-ом блоке?

Comment: И внутри каждой следующей странички будет такой же квадрат? Или уже невидимая центральная точка?) Хотя, это может быть один общий квадрат поверх всех сжатых страничек... Можно попробовать превращать `transform: scale(0,0)` в `(1,1)`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, внутри следующей странички (блока) по задумке будет новый контент, а сама страничка (блок) типа развернётся из этого квадрата. И все, больше с квадратом не будет манипуляций)